# How to prevent constant movement

Tags: java

So I have this code for moving a pointer up and down in a menu. The only problem is it moves way too fast to even stop on any of the selections. It does go to each one, but even just a quick tap of the button the pointer moves down 3 selections. If you go up and down a few times it will go to the selection you want, but it's a hassle. So is there a way to maybe disable movement for about half a second?

```
        if(Game.stateEngine.menuState == StateEngine.MenuState.ITEM)
        {
            if(Input.dn && Game.pointer.y < 430)
            {
                Game.pointer.y += 15;
            }
            if(Input.up && Game.pointer.y > 172)
            {
                Game.pointer.y -= 15;
            }
            if(Input.x && Game.stateEngine.menuState != StateEngine.MenuState.MAIN)
            {
                Game.stateEngine.menuState = StateEngine.MenuState.MAIN;
                Menu.firstPass = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer (delay, countdown, whatever you want to call it). Each time a menu movement is applied, reset the timer. Do not allow another movement until the timer has expired.

Unlike the event-based approach, this still allows you to hold a key and move through a menu, but only at a limited speed.

An implementation might look like:

```
double m_LastMove = 0;
double const kMoveSpeedSeconds = 0.5;

void MoveUp() {
  double now = GetTime();

  if ((now - m_LastMove) >= kMoveSpeedSeconds)
  {
    m_Item = m_Item - 1;
    m_LastMove = now;
  }
}
```

That allows a fixed slow speed of scrolling through menus and it requires no continuous update loop on account of using absolute times instead of deltas. Your game might prefer 64-bit integers or some other type for absolute times; just don't use a single-precision `float`.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems usually happens when the key state is checked at each frame.
What you want to do is use the OS event that signals a "key press", or "key down". Note that if you do the same for the mouse, the "mouse **UP**" event is the one, contrasting with key input.

Then the repetition will happen after a delay, this is handled by the system input thread, or they keyboard class driver, who knows. Of course you could emulate this behavior as well, by using chornometers that checks the timeline of the repetition state machine, but using system settings is nice.